# It there any way to find out is incoming call screen is being shown over my application?

Tags: windows-phone-7

It there any way to find out if there is an incoming telephone call screen being shown over my application? In fact, while we wouldn't accept call - the application would not be deactivated, so is there any API method or maybe some workarounds like screenshoting and verifying by pixel ? :-)

Comment: can you reformulate your question? it is hard to understand what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell if the user is receiving an incoming telephone call using the RootFrame.Obscured event as described here: 
http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/02/11/silverlight-for-windows-phone-programming-tip-6.aspx

Comment: Note that this event covers any obscurring of the screen. Not just incoming calls.